# Neural Network for Image Arrangement depending on Image Parameters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have set of images which are arranged in different manner by different persons. I have computed four parameters for each image. Position of any image in above said arrangement depends upon these Four parameters. So now I want to find out this relation between parameters of image and its position in arrangement. This relation I will also be using for finding out position for any incoming New image depending on its Four parameters derived.  I am intending to use neural network. So which net would preferable in my case....

Comment: Have you researched neural networks? Have you narrowed your options down? Can you implement any of them? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, we got some papers on describing use of feed forward net for soft decision making, but they haven't given any proper reason, why that particular net was selected.